# Tablas dinamicas python

Tags: python, excel, pivot, tabla-dinámica

Recibo diario un reporte con esta data:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

TOdos los valores de los cabeceras pueden cambiar aunque el campo de Fechas siempre se va a mantener igual para cada cliente, a que me refiero:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que necesito es que en mi archivo llamado Data.xlsx me vaya cargando los datos como en una tabla dinamica. Lea mis reportes diarios y los acomode en mi archivo Data.xlsx de la forma que expreso abajo

Algo asi seria:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Porque se tiene que guardar en un excel, ademas veo el problema que si no tenes un identificador único de cliente en el reporte, va a ser complicado vincularlos ya que con el nombre no basta, recomendaria usar una pequeña base de datos en ves de excel para almacenarlos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si he entendido tu problema, puedes usar `pandas.DataFrame.merge` y usar la columna `Cliente` como clave única. Sobreentiendo que cada **nuevo xlsx no contiene fechas que ya estén presentes en actualizaciones anteriores**, es decir, que no hay solapamiento de columnas entre los nuevos datos y los anteriores.

Partiendo de dos archivos xlsx tal que:

**archivo1.xlsx:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**archivo2.xlsx:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Podemos hacer:

```
import pandas as pd
import pandas.io.formats.excel

# Leemos ambos archivos y los cargamos en DataFrames
df1 = pd.read_excel("archivo1.xlsx")
df2 = pd.read_excel("archivo2.xlsx")

# Pivotamos ambas tablas
df1 = df1.pivot(index = "Cliente", columns='Fecha', values='Revenue')
df2 = df2.pivot(index = "Cliente", columns='Fecha', values='Revenue')

# Unimos ambos dataframes tomando la columna "Cliente" como clave
merged = pd.merge(df1, df2, right_index =True, left_index = True, how='outer')
merged.sort_index(axis=1, inplace=True)

# Creamos el xlsx de salida
pandas.io.formats.excel.header_style = None

with pd.ExcelWriter("Data.xlsx",
                    engine='xlsxwriter',
                    date_format='dd/mm/yyyy',
                    datetime_format='dd/mm/yyyy') as writer:

    merged.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')
```

**output.xlsx:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

---

Si partes de un archivo `Data.xlsx` previo que quieres actualizar con otro con el formato de `Archivo1.xlsx` y `Archivo2.xlsx` basta con pivotar este último archivo y aplicar el `merge` sobre el Dataframe del primero:

```
import pandas as pd
import pandas.io.formats.excel

data = pd.read_excel("Data.xlsx",  index_col='Cliente')
new_data = pd.read_excel("archivo.xlsx")
new_data = new_data.pivot(index = "Cliente", columns='Fecha', values='Revenue')
merged = pd.merge(data, new_data, right_index =True, left_index = True, how='outer')
merged.sort_index(axis=1, inplace=True)

pandas.io.formats.excel.header_style = None
with pd.ExcelWriter("Data.xlsx",
                    engine='xlsxwriter',
                    date_format='dd/mm/yyyy',
                    datetime_format='dd/mm/yyyy') as writer:
    merged.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')
```

**Data.xlsx (inicial)**:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**archivo.xlsx (actualización):**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Data.xlsx (final)**:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si al final vas a manejar una cantidad considerable de datos, existen mejores formas de hacer esto que usando archivos de Excel. Una base de datos sería una opción considerablemente más eficiente, generando un xlsx a partir de ella cuando sea requerido, pero almacenando y realizando las actualizaciones en la propia base de datos.